# Which two statements are true regarding procedures?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Procedure PROCESS_EMP references table EMP. Procedure UPDATE_EMP updates rows of table EMP through procedure PROCESS_EMP. There is a remote procedure QUERY_EMP that queries the EMP table through the local procedure PROCESS_EMP. The dependency mode is set to TIMESTAMP in this session. Which two statements are true ?

1) If the signature of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, the EMP table is invalidated.

2) If internal logic of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, UPDATE_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the first time.

3) If the signature of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, UPDATE_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the first time.

4) If internal logic of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, QUERY_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the first time.

5) If internal logic of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, QUERY_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the second time.

As far as I know about signature is combination of return type and list of arguments.

1) If signature of PROCESS_EMP changes, it has nothing to do with EMP table as it itself is referencing EMP.

2) This is correct option. UPDATE_EMP is using PROCESS_EMP for updation of EMP table. If internal logic of PROCESS_EMP changes, then how it affects UPDATE_EMP ? If UPDATE_EMP is using PROCESS_EMP, then it should be calling it. Changes in internal logic is contained in body which is in PROCESS_EMP, not in UPDATE_EMP.

3) I thought this must be correct. But it is wrong. If the changes in signature are made in PROCESS_EMP. Like if return type or number of arguments or both are modified, then the way of calling would be affected. So, UPDATE_EMP should be affected. Why is it false ?

4) and 5) 4 point is incorrect. I did not get this "first time" and "second time". Why second time ? Why not first time ? 5 point is correct.*

Comment: My answers to the above, based on my minimal knowledge of Oracle's recompilation logic, are 1) False, 2) Depends on how UPDATE_EMP is invoked, 3) Same as (2), 4) False, and 5) False.  Any DBA's out there got a better read on this one?

Answer (score 1):

3rd and 5th points are right.

You have the reasons fir the 3rd point.

Reasons for 5th point to be true:

- The dependency mode is set to `TIMESTAMP`.
- When the internal logic of the procedure `PROCESS_EMP` is modified and successfully recompiles, its `TIMESTAMP` changes. You can check that by querying the `USER_OBJECTS` view.
- All the procedures dependent on `PROCESS_EMP` are immediately invalidated. You can check this also by querying the `USER_OBJECTS` view. Hence when these procedures, like `UPDATE_EMP`, are recompiled when they are called for the first time.
- But any remote procedures, like `QUERY_EMP`, that are dependent on `PROCESS_EMP` are not immediately invalidated. These are invalidated after they are invoked for the first time after the dependent procedure is recompiled. Hence `QUERY_EMP` does not recompile when invoked for the first time. You can check this by querying the `USER_OBJECTS` view on the remote database before and after invoking `QUERY_EMP`.
- When `QUERY_EMP` is invoked for the second time, as its status is invalid, it has to be recompiled and as there is no change in the signature of `PROCESS_EMP` it successfully recompiles and executes.

For more information read Oracle Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_pc.htm).

Comment: We disagree on #3, but that may only be because of version differences.  My example is for 11g, which uses [fine-grained invalidation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17125/adfns_dependencies.htm#CHDJIIFC).

Comment: Ok... I saw the tag as `oracle10g`, that's why.

Comment: @jonearles: In #3, by "All the procedures" I mean all procedures in the same database. The procedures in the remote database are not immediately invalidated, as far as I know. :)

Comment: Woops, I missed the 10g tag!  After Googling this question, I see that it was created for 10g.  However, I believe the relevant exam is now only for 11g.

Comment: OCP, i.e., 1z0-146 is for 11g. If the questioner is attempting for OCA, there are two- 1z0-144 for 11g and 1z0-147 for 10g. Depends.

Answer (score 1):

3 and 5.

But don't take my word for it, let's test it.

**Create test objects**

```
--Remote dependency mode
alter session set remote_dependencies_mode = timestamp;

--Table
drop table emp purge;
create table emp(id number, name varchar2(100));
insert into emp values(1, 'asdf');
commit;

--Database link - you don't need two databases, you can link to yourself
drop database link myself;
create database link myself connect to <user> identified by <password> using '<database>';
select * from dual@myself;

--Procedures
create or replace procedure process_emp(action_type in varchar2) is
    v_count number;
begin
    if action_type = 'U' then
        update emp set name = upper(name);
    elsif action_type = 'Q' then
        select count(*) into v_count from emp;
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace procedure update_emp is
begin
    process_emp('U');
end;
/

create or replace procedure query_emp is
begin
    process_emp@myself('Q');
end;
/

--Initial object times
select object_name, last_ddl_time, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('PROCESS_EMP', 'UPDATE_EMP', 'QUERY_EMP')
order by last_ddl_time;

PROCESS_EMP 2013-04-02 00:25:47 VALID
UPDATE_EMP  2013-04-02 00:25:48 VALID
QUERY_EMP   2013-04-02 00:25:49 VALID
```

**Test**

1) If the signature of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, the EMP table is invalidated.

*False* - nothing to even test there.  There's no such thing as an invalidated table.  (Except maybe for object-relational tables, but I don't think that applies here.)

2) If internal logic of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, UPDATE_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the first time.

*False* - UPDATE_EMP is still valid, and does not recompile.  The LAST_DDL_TIME does not change.  Normally, a procedure is only known by its signature - if that doesn't change then there's no need for anything else to change.

```
create or replace procedure process_emp(action_type in varchar2) is
    v_count number;
begin
    if action_type = 'U' then
        update emp set name = upper(name);
    elsif action_type = 'Q' then
        select count(*)+1 into v_count from emp;
    end if;
end;
/

select object_name, last_ddl_time, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('PROCESS_EMP', 'UPDATE_EMP', 'QUERY_EMP')
order by last_ddl_time;

UPDATE_EMP  2013-04-02 00:25:48 VALID
QUERY_EMP   2013-04-02 00:25:49 VALID
PROCESS_EMP 2013-04-02 00:29:20 VALID
```

3) If the signature of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, UPDATE_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the first time.

*True* - Changing the parameters potentially changes the way the procedure is called.  Most changes will cause a failure, but there are many cases where
the dependent procedures will recompile and everything will be fine.  For example, if you add a defaulted parameter:

```
create or replace procedure process_emp(action_type in varchar2, new_param in varchar2 default null) is
    v_count number;
begin
    if action_type = 'U' then
        update emp set name = upper(name);
    elsif action_type = 'Q' then
        select count(*)+1 into v_count from emp;
    end if;
end;
/

--Now the object is invalid:
select status from user_objects where object_name in ('UPDATE_EMP');
INVALID

--But no need to worry, just run it and it will automatically recompile and work correctly:
begin
    update_emp;
end;
/

select status from user_objects where object_name in ('UPDATE_EMP');
VALID
```

4) If internal logic of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, QUERY_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the first time.

*False* - QUERY_EMP is still VALID, but will fail when invoked the first time, and will not recompile.  In fact, even changing the parameters, as we've done above, will not invalidate this.

```
select object_name, last_ddl_time, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('QUERY_EMP')
order by last_ddl_time;

QUERY_EMP   2013-04-02 00:25:49 VALID

begin
    query_emp@myself;
end;
/

ORA-04062: timestamp of procedure "JHELLER.PROCESS_EMP" has been changed
ORA-06512: at "JHELLER.QUERY_EMP", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 2

View program sources of error stack?
```

5) If internal logic of procedure PROCESS_EMP is modified and successfully recompiles, QUERY_EMP gets invalidated and will recompile when invoked for the second time.

*True* - QUERY_EMP will get invalidated (although not until after the first time), and then recompiles correctly the second time. The query runs, and the LAST_DDL_TIME is now updated.

```
begin
    query_emp@myself;
end;
/

select object_name, last_ddl_time, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('QUERY_EMP')
order by last_ddl_time;

QUERY_EMP   2013-04-02 00:37:01 VALID
```